# How does the passive item Unity add damage from your other guns?

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

The passive item Unity supposedly adds 2% of the damage of every other gun you're carrying to your currently equipped gun.  How does it handle things like shotguns (which have multiple bullets that consist of most of their damage), charged weapons (which have different damage ratings), or explosive weapons (which deal at least part of their damage as an explosion)?  How does it calculate the damage from beam weapons?  The exact damage calculation is sure to be less than straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

**Shotguns** - Base damage per bullet, not per spray

**Beams** - Base damage per tick, most beams tick 10 times a second.

---

For example, lets say I have the Regular Shotgun, the Mac-10, the Disintegrator, and the AWP

Damage bonuses would be calculated as follows:

4 (Reg Shotgun) + 3.5 (MAC) + 7 (Disintegrator) + 40 (AWP) = 54.5
54.5 * 0.02 = 1.09 Bonus Damage per bullet

Shotguns are the best weapons to use with unity, as the damage bonus is multiplied by the number of shots in each spray. Barring that, the best kinds of weapons are ones that fire fast, like the MAC-10 or Patriot. Keep in mind the gun you're currently using isn't included in the bonus damage calculation.